# Multiple singular nominatives as a collective subject

Tags: nominativus

Can multiple singular things act as a collective subject? I am trying to understand the following expression from Horace:

```
fama decus divitiis parent
```

So, *fama* and *decus* are both singular nominatives. However, the verb of the sentence is third person plural, *parent* (they appear). So, it appears (paret) that *fama* and *decus* seem to be acting as a collective subject of the sentence, so take a plural form of a verb. Is that right? If so, then the sense of the sentence seems to be, `reputation and honor appear with wealth`.

Also, should I treat *divitiis* as ablative with *cum* understood, or should I treat it as ablative of agency? It changes the meaning. So, does it mean "with wealth" or "by wealth"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your supposition is correct about the two singular nominatives agreeing with a plural verb:

> **317.** Two or more singular subjects take a verb in the plural.
>
> *Pater et avus mortuī sunt. His father and grandfather are dead.*
>
> ([Allen and Greenough, *Latin Grammar*](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/agreement))

However, the sense of *[pareo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=pareo&la=la#lexicon)* is *to submit to*:

> Fame and glory submit to riches.

To answer your question about *divitiis*, it's in the dative and serves as a complement the verb *pareo*:

> to submit **to riches**

Comment: I.e. "dīvitiīs" is a dative (with "pārēre").

Comment: @Batavulus. Yes, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Just b/c Tyler had suggested abl. :-)